# C# .Net + MongoDB Atlas connection string MongoDB.Driver.Legacy error when trying to run Client

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-atlas

I've set up a Cluster + Collection in a MongoDB Atlas database.
I'm trying to follow tutorials such as this one:
[Bookstore | Using ASP.NET Core 5.0 and MongoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNepwvCcKXA)

my code is as follows, with <> replaced with real data of course:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<clustername>.ck3ra.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
var database = client.GetDatabase("<database>");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("validation");
ShowMessage(collection.ToString());
```

The error i'm getting is:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver.Legacy' or one of its dependencies. An argument was out of its legal range. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131502)
> File name: 'MongoDB.Driver.Legacy' ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
> Parameter name: length

I'm not sure what's wrong here because I am writing the connection string exactly as per the **Connect** instructions on the MongoDB website, as well as the other tutorials...

Would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you added mongocsharpdriver packge to your project?

Comment: Your above code doesn't use Legacy driver, it looks like something different is wrong on your side. Create a simple console application and check this behavior there. I think it will work without any issues, then check the difference with the main app

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your have added the [mongocsharpdrive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/) package to your package and it’s dependencies.
As you are targeting to .net5 so please consider the .net standard 2.0 dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! I've added it through the NuGet packages, but I doesn't seem to make a differenece... any way to test if I've done it correctly...?

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky have you added the dependencies as mentioned in the given link in my answer?

Comment: Yes it appears in the packages.config file in the project if that's what you mean. I don't want to install it manually via a CLI because the project is to be compiled for external users and i'm not sure how they will use it without installing it manually, so I must include it as some package within the project compilation process (such as NuGet).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'consider the .net standard 2.0 dependencies'? perhaps i'm missing some file because I still can't solve the issue...

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky is this issue resolved or still facing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I didn't find a solution so I moved to something else. Unresolved I would say... but no resources to test it again :(